# How can I get movies/series with a specific genre using IMDb api?

Tags: api, search, video, series, imdb

Well I'm using IMDb-api in my app and need to be able to **browse** *movies/series* by their genre [like this in IMDb website](https://www.imdb.com/feature/genre/?ref_=nv_ch_gr). And I looked into [IMDb-API Documentation](https://imdb-api.com/api) and they haven't **mentioned** such a thing in its documentation.
[image]

I have already tried `https://imdb-api.com/en/API/SearchTitle/{APIKey}/?genres=sci-fi` but this was the response I received:

> "Invalid request. See more information at [https://imdb-api.com/api#/{lang?}/API/Search/{expression}](https://imdb-api.com/api#/%7Blang?%7D/API/Search/%7Bexpression%7D)  - Search APIs: Search, SearchTitle, SearchName, SearchEpisode, SearchCompany, SearchKeyword, SearchAll-header"

Comment: Maybe try looking at: [advancedSearch](https://imdb-api.com/api#AdvancedSearch-header)?